# SPFx React REST API 403 error

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, spfx-webparts, react-webpart

I have created SPFx webpart with React. I am calling REST API to get documents from document library and it's work perfectly in workbench but in SharePoint page i am getting error **403 - Forbidden**

```
private GetDetails(selectedFolder: string) {
    const queryString =
      "?$select=Title,Name,ServerRelativeUrl&$expand=File&$filter=Title ne null&$orderby=Title asc";
    var URL ="/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('" +selectedFolder + "')/files" + queryString;
    var options: Array<IPropertyPaneDropdownOption> = new Array<IPropertyPaneDropdownOption>();
    this.getItems(URL).then((iMapsItems: any[]) => {
      iMapsItems.map((items: any) => {
        var strFileDisplayName = items.Title;
        var strFileUrl = items.ServerRelativeUrl;        
      });
      if (
        options.length &&
        ((this.properties.scriptUrl && this.properties.scriptUrl == "/") ||
          !this.properties.scriptUrl)
      )
      this.properties.scriptUrl = options[0].key.toString();
      this.ddlImapFileSelector = options;
      this.context.propertyPane.refresh();
    });
 }
private getItems(url: string): Promise<any[]> {
    const queryUrl: string = this.properties.siteName + url;
    return this.requester
      .get(queryUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
      .then((response: any) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((json: { value: ISPIMapsItems[] }) => {
        return json.value.map((task: ISPIMapsItems) => {
          return task;
        });
      });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean it is working in SharePoint workbench but not working in SharePoint Page when added as a web part from app catalog? Can you please add the code you are using and any other details of an error?

Comment: Exactly. Shared code

Comment: what is the value of selected folder in workbench and on the page?

Comment: Same value in both. selected-folder is the property pane value(In my scenario i have created cascading drop down in property pane)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have set the `isDomainIsolated` property to `true` in the `package-solution.json` file.

Modify the value to `false` and then do the process again to package the webpart and re-upload it in the app catalog site collection. Should work now in the SharePoint pages.

Comment: Thanks. It's working